# find_all does not find text in mixed content

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a little bit of screen scraping code in Python, using BeautifulSoup, that is giving me headache. A small change to the html made my code break, but I can't see why it fails to work. This is basically a demo of how the html looked when parsed:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup("""
<td>
    <a href="https://alink.com">
        Foo Some text Bar
    </a>
</td>
""")
links = soup.find_all('a',text=re.compile('Some text'))
links[0]['href'] # => "https://alink.com"
```

After an upgrade, the a tag body now includes an img tag, which makes the code break.

```
<td>
    <a href="https://alink.com">
        <img src="dummy.gif" >
        Foo Some text Bar
    </a>
</td>
```

'links' is now an empty list, so the regex is not finding anything.
I hacked around it by matching on the text alone, then finding
its parent, but that seems even more fragile:

```
links = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Some text'))
links[0].parent['href'] # => "https://alink.com"
```

What is the addition of an img tag as a sibling to the text
content breaking the search done by BeautifulSoup, and is there
a way of modifying the first code to work?

Comment: why not `next(link["href"] for link in soup.find_all('a') if "Some text" in link.text)`

Comment: seems fine. what does the next() call do?

Comment: just returns  the first match which will be the link you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example works only if `a.string` is not `None` i.e., iff the text is the only child.

As a workaround,  you could use a function predicate:

```
a = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and tag.has_attr('href') and 'Some text' in tag.text)
print(a['href'])
# -> 'https://alink.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the 2nd example has an incomplete `img` tag:

it should be either

```
<img src="dummy.gif" />
Foo Some text Bar
```

or

```
<img src="dummy.gif" > </img>
Foo Some text Bar
```

Instead, it is parsed as

```
<img src="dummy.gif" >
Foo Some text Bar
</img>
```

So the element found isn't `a` any longer, but `img`, whose parent is `a`.

Comment: This behaviour actually turned out to be library specific. I got some parsing code to work with the Python distro on my Mac, but it did not work with my Linux distro. The incomplete img tag was regarded as a parent in one runtime, but not the other, where it was regarded a sibling. Gotta love it.